# how to log out the current user in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I have used the below link to end a session.

http://pure-essence.net/2010/02/14/jquery-session-timeout-countdown/

In that i am able to redirect to the login page. But the user is not logging off. Just it is 
redirecting to that page. But it is not logging out. How can i log out the session in that case. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Answer  : Use `FormsAuthentication.SignOut();`

Long Answer

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
}

private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
{
    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
    {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

Use `[Authorize]` above the actions which you don't want the user to do after logging out. This you can do by adding this attribute above actions individually or marking the entire class with `[Authorize]` so that all methods can now be only be accessed by authenticated users.

Hope this helps.

Comment: where should i invoke the `FormsAuthentication.SignOut();`

Comment: invoke it where you want to end user's session.

Comment: In the login page controller

Comment: In the code before i redirection i am calling a ajax function to one of the controller and in the action i have given the `FormsAuthentication.SignOut();` that does not work

Comment: if you want to end user's session on click of something like a logout button, use an action link to direct the button to the `LogOff` Action

Comment: Actually it is going to the action but the user in not logging off still i am able to manage my account after that executes also.

Comment: use `[Authorize]` above the actions which you dont want the user to do after logging out.

Answer (score 2):

```
AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

This should work in newer versions.